# Set default error code for all occurrences of Rule().NotEmpty();

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I need to set the ErrorCode field of every validation failure of the same kind.

We have a list of application errors that we might send when an error occurs in our API. How can I force FluentValidation to always return a specific error code in the ValidationFailure object without having to manually add to every rule the `.WithErrorCode(myErrorCode)`

Right now I would have to do the following all the time.

```
RuleFor(x => x.SomeField).NotEmpty().WithErrorCode(errorCodes['EmptyField']);
```

I'm hoping for something I can set globally that will use a default error code for a specific rule.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to write your own extension method for that:

```
public static class FluentValidationExtendions
{
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TProperty> NotEmptyWithDefaultCode<T, TProperty>(this IRuleBuilder<T, TProperty> ruleBuilder, string errorCode = null)
    {
        return ruleBuilder.NotEmpty().WithErrorCode(errorCode ?? errorCodes['EmptyField']);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
RuleFor(x => x.SomeField).NotEmptyWithDefaultCode();
```